# Uploading file using Jersey over RESTfull service and The resource configuration is not modifiable?

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey, jersey-2.0

```
@Path("file.upload")
public class UploadFileService {
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    System.out.println("-----------------UploadFileService------------------1.");
    // Should we use a disk or DB? Decided to use DISK
    // Path should be read from properties-files
    String uploadedFileLocation = "//uploaded/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    // All went OK
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

```
 WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.insame.service.UploadFileService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.

SEVERE:   WebModule[/insame]StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.insame.service.UploadFileService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=MethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.insame.service.UploadFileService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@47bee27a]}, handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.insame.service.UploadFileService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:410)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
```

I implemented test service like this under the `UploadFileService`:

```
@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String countREST() {
    return "1 one 1";
}
```

and I got this exception to log:

```
FINE:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" 

"/webresources/file.upload/count" "GET")
SEVERE:   WebModule[/insame]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:257)
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[com.insame.service.ApplicationConfig]: Allocate exception for servlet com.insame.service.ApplicationConfig
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
```

**Environment**

- Netbeans7.3.1
- Glassfish 4.0
- Jersey 2 with Glassfish 4.0

Comment: For `ResourceConfig` solution see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43926819/548473

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In order to use multipart in your Jersey application you need to register [MultiPartFeature](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your application, i.e.:

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // Add your resources.
        resources.add(UploadFileService.class);

        // Add additional features such as support for Multipart.
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);

        return resources;
    }
}
```

For more information see [Multipart](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart) section in the Jersey Users Guide.

For the second issue you're facing try to restart the GlassFish server, I am not sure how NetBeans are reloading the Jersey app after a change (if this doesn't help, please post your `ApplicationConfig`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Error message changed and I found one error in my pom.xml. I was using old multipart version in my pom.xml. WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Providers] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide(@Context Providers, Provider<CloseableService>)]

Comment: This might be related to having some of the Jersey 2.x bits in your `.war` (while they're on GF classpath at the same time). Can you mark `jersey-media-multipart` artifact in your pom.xml as provided? It's already a part of GF 4.0.

Comment: That was it!! Now it is working! <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: I am not using Maven but have the same configuration but the  GF4 jersey classes are NOT found ! What can I do ?

Comment: I had this problem after merging an old Jersey 1 to Jersey 2 project. I think the solution is not the accepted answer, but rather the fix to the POM and web XML files...

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem and wanted to avoid creating a custom application class. It is not well documented, but if you want to add Multipart functionality, all you have to do is add this to your web.xml jersey servlet config:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I also added a loggingfilter.

Comment: Your solution is the BEST!

Comment: I can't get this to work either. Does it need to be somewhere specific order-wise? Do you have a gist of your entire pom by any chance?

Comment: This is the easiest approach and works like a charm! Highly recommended!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jetty server and jersey servlet, then you can solve this problem by adding the following code in your main class where you have started the jetty server,

> ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
>                     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");             jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
>
> ```
>       // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/classes to load.
>       jerseyServlet
>               .setInitParameter(
>                       "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
>                       <Your entry point class's canonical name>
>                               + ";org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just minor clarification

Use

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

Not

```
com.sun.jersey.*
```

Did work for me only when used `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.*`

In ApplicationConfig just register MultiPartFeature as

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        resources.add(UploadFileService.class);
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hlleo guys,i'm using wildfly server, can i use  import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.* in my ApplicationConfig , if yes can you tell what is the dependency that i should add in my pom.xml , because im getting this error in my project : javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition of content type: multipart/form-data;, thak you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jersey 1.9.1. org.glassfish...... works well with Jersey 2. For Jersey 1 you better use com.sun... classes.

Comment: Instead of adding two posts for your answer, I'd suggest that you edit your post of your first attempt to answer the question (i.e. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42960464/3519000)). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @FormDataParam("file") equivalent of FormDataMultiPart if you want it using annotation.

Used as given below sample code extract:

```
public Response uploadFile( **@FormDataParam("file")** InputStream fileInputStream,
             @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
```