# Import jersey-media-multipart on Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: jersey, glassfish, multipart

I get into the problem. Please help me to solve it!

I don't know if I imported the two libraries well! -> [image: my setup]
Depend on the picture, look at jersey-media-multipart-2.17.jar and mimepull-1.9.3.jar, are they become libraries yet?

Web.xml seems like didn't accept my init-param may I had put wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
            30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
<servlet>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

How to place init-program into the Web.xml? Because it is not accept what I have place it.

Error: [Error occurred after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mSMB.png)

I have stucked long time ago without solution.
I hope someone give me solution!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You did not describe what the problem is....

Comment: How are you configuring the JAX-RS application?

Comment: Thank you! I have added questions.

Comment: For JAX-RS, I didn't know because It was done by someone else before.

Comment: This answer can help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837257/how-to-write-jersey-multipart-webapp-tomcat-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837257/how-to-write-jersey-multipart-webapp-tomcat-server)