# JAX-RS Multipart with com.sun.jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, multipart, karaf

I have a REST service hosted inside Karaf, which is working fine with all requests except for multipart requests. I'm using the [`com.sun.jersey`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey) packages, as I have only succeeded in hosting these inside of Karaf to be accessed over HTTP.

When I try to receive the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) inside the POST and call the [`getParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) method on it, I get the error:

> IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet

I have found that I am missing the [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html) annotation on my servlet, so I added this to the servlet implementation I am using. I extend `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` and add the annotation to that class. But this does not work.

I've also tried using my own extension of the `HttpServlet` class, that reproduces the error:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class MultipartServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            final Collection<Part> parts = httpRequest.getParts();

            System.out.println("There are " + parts.size() + " parts");
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("MEGA FAIL");
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }

        super.service(request, response);
    }
}
```

I've seen the approach using [`org.glassfish.jersey`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey) packages that makes registers the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29534950/308012) class with the `ResourceConfig`, but I haven't been able to get these packages accessible over HTTP inside of Karaf (the services appear to register without error, but all requests return 404 responses).

Comment: Why are you trying to use multipart in a servlet when you want to do it with Jersey. See [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/) for Jersey 1.x multipart support

Comment: That article uses specifically named parts from the multipart request. I need to be able to handle an unknown number of parts within the body of the method itself, which is why I was trying to use the `HttpServletRequest`. Is there a way to achieve this using Jersey instead?

Comment: @peeskillet It's probably also worth highlighting that I'm running this inside of Karaf, so I've got this servlet registered against the `HttpService` installed with Karaf, as that was the only way I had managed to host a RESTful service within Karaf that was accessible via HTTP (i.e. on localhost:8181). If there's a better way of approaching that, then any direction would be appreciated

Comment: _"I need to be able to handle an unknown number of parts within the body of the method itself"_ - Use [FormDataMultiPart](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/contribs/jersey-multipart/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.java#L85) as the method parameter. You don't need to use any annotations.

Comment: @peeskillet I'm guessing I'm missing something, but when trying to use that as the method parameter of the service with no annotations I get a **400 Bad Request** response. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @peeskillet Never mind, I fixed the Bad Request response by removing the `Content-Type` header in the request (for some reason). So the `FormDataMultiPart` is now working :-) Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the Servlet multipart, you just use [Jersey's multipart support](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/). In the example in the link, it uses named parts. If you want to be able to process all unknown parts, you can just use [`FormDataMultiPart`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/contribs/jersey-multipart/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.java#L85) as the method parameter. This way you can access all the parts with `getFields()`

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response post(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
    final Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> = multiPart.getFields();
}
```