# MultiPartFeature with javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat7

I'm trying to upload a file using Jersey but I'm facing a lot of trouble. I saw that i have to configure `MultiPartFeature` to make things happen but I couldn't make it work. I understand that i have to enable multipart feature on jersey but that's the problem.

I tried to configure a custom Application and `ResourceConfig` but for some reason when I do this my rest services stop working. I also tried to add an `<init-param>` enabling MultiPart but didn't work as well.

I'm using Tomcat7, Spring, Jersey with Jackson

These are couple of the approaches I tried.

[org.glassfish.jersey upload file with FormDataContentDisposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406331/org-glassfish-jersey-upload-file-with-formdatacontentdisposition)

[Uploading file using Jersey over RESTfull service and The resource configuration is not modifiable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252990/uploading-file-using-jersey-over-restfull-service-and-the-resource-configuration)

I'm using the default servlet configuration `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` to map my rest services. And I guess this is the whole problem but as I mentioned before when I tried to map a custom [`Application` ou `ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) I get other problems

This is my current configuration. With this configuration everything works great except the Multipart

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/not-found.html</location>
</error-page>

<context-param>
    <param-name>STORAGE_PROPERTY</param-name>
    <param-value>${user.home}/tec-imovel/STORAGE/property</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>STORAGE_USER</param-name>
    <param-value>${user.home}/tec-imovel/STORAGE/user</param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
        <param-value>A2592000 </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
        <param-value>A2592000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
        <param-value>A2592000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security Char Encoding Filter-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Servlet declaration can be omitted in which case it would be automatically
    added by Jersey-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Upload de imagens de usuario -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImagemUsuarioUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tecimovel.upload.servlet.ImagemUsuarioUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImagemUsuarioUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imagem-usuario-upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Upload de imagens de imovel -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImagemImovelUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tecimovel.upload.servlet.ImagemImovelUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImagemImovelUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/imagem-imovel-upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet de download de imagens do imovel -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DownloadImagemImovelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tecimovel.download.servlet.DownloadImagemImovelServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadImagemImovelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download-imagem-imovel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet de download de imagens do usuario -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DownloadImagemUsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tecimovel.download.servlet.DownloadImagemUsuarioServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadImagemUsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download-imagem-usuario/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.web.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Open Session View -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>oemInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>oemInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <description>PostgreSQL DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TECIMOVELDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<filter>
    <filter-name>crawlerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tecimovel.filter.CrawlerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>crawlerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>tec-imovel</groupId>
<artifactId>tec-imovel</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>tec-imovel</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
        <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <!-- <version>1.5.6</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!--LOGGING SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <!-- EHCache uses slf4j for logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>tec-imovel</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- <plugin> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.1.5</version> -->
        <!-- <configuration> -->
        <!-- <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml> -->
        <!-- <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate> -->
        <!-- </configuration> -->
        <!-- <executions> -->
        <!-- <execution> -->
        <!-- <id>generate-rebel-xml</id> -->
        <!-- <phase>process-resources</phase> -->
        <!-- <goals> -->
        <!-- <goal>generate</goal> -->
        <!-- </goals> -->
        <!-- </execution> -->
        <!-- </executions> -->
        <!-- </plugin> -->


    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

**Service that receives uploaded file**

```
@Path("/migracao")
public class MigracaoRS {

    @Autowired
    private MigracaoGenericService migracaoGenericService;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioController usuarioController;

    //IF I DON'T COMMENT THIS METHOD THE SERVER DOESN'T EVEN START BECAUSE OF THE MULTIPART THING
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        migracaoGenericService.migrar(uploadedInputStream, usuarioController.getUsuarioLogado());
    }
}
```

**Init param in jersey servlet. If I add this init-param my rest services stop working :(**

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You tried to add the classnames init-param inside the javax.ws.rs.Application servlet definition? Also what result are you getting that says its not working?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the comment in the code. But when I set the init-param in the servlet definition, it works fine. Without it, I get the same result you're facing. Can you show exactly how you used the init-param. Maybe you put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Another thing, you already have a `<jersey.version>` property in your pom. You should use it in your `<version>` definitions. I see you're mixing versions. You should use `${jersey.version}` instead of the static version to keep them consistent. Actually you don't even need the version. That's what the `bom` is for. You could completely get rid of the version in the jersey dependency definitions, and it will all be the same

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for you help. I put how I set the init-param in the last part of the question. If I set the init-param my rest services stop working :(

Comment: @peeskillet When I said my rest services stop working I mean they all return 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so the original servlet configuration you had

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

allows for registration of classes through classpath scanning. Once you add the `<init-param>` `...provider.classnames`, you are saying to Jersey, "don't register all those resources and providers you found on the classpath, I will register them myself".

So to fix that, you can add the `<init-param>` to scan your project packages, or any other packages on the classpath (like other jars).

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        the.packages.to.scan,
        multiple.pacakges,
        can.be.separated.by.comma
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

It's not the same as scanning the classpath, but for the most part, all your resources should be in your project anyway, and if not, just register the jar package explicitly.

- In general, see [Application Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) for other deployment modes and configurations

Comment: I try add the package scan as you said but I got another error. It seams the Entity to Json conversion is not working after I add this init-param. In this [link](http://pastebin.com/d1Vt5EmG) you can see how I configure the Jersey servlet and the exception message

Comment: You can register the JacksonFeature either by class (to the ...classnames init-param) `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature` (comma separated) or register the package  `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` (in the packages init-param)

Comment: After I also added this package to scan "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs"  my rest services are working again. Now i'm gonna try to make the upload file works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier for you to use JSON as consumer and pass your file as byte array this will make it part of you json request.

Comment: It seams a good alternative. Could you give more details or put in some direction. Tks